# Add Panel with GridLayout onto Background Image

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I wanted to create a simple TicTacToe game in java by myself.
But currently I´m struggling with the first issue..

The GUI only displays the Gamefield itself (the "grid") OR the invisble buttons (when you click on them, it displays a X or O)
But never both of them?

I need the gamefield Image as the background and on that the buttons.. But I cant get it working.. I already tried using a third JPanel as the "main" panel with a FlowLayout and added the two other panels onto it.
I created some simple icons and a backround grid in paint.. icons are 200x200 and the grid 600x600 (same as my frame size)

"X-icon"      : https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGlZM.png

"O-icon"      : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnoQd.png

"Background"  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF5yW.png

I Hope anyone can help me out :)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class TicTacToe implements ActionListener{

    ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel gamefield;
    JPanel background;
    JLabel backgroundLabel;
    ImageIcon backgroundImage = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\adnan\\Programmieren\\Games\\TicTacToe\\field.png");
    ImageIcon iconX = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\adnan\\Programmieren\\Games\\TicTacToe\\iconX.png");
    ImageIcon iconO = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\adnan\\Programmieren\\Games\\TicTacToe\\iconO.png");
    int player = 1;

    void createGameField(){

        background = new JPanel();
        background.setPreferredSize(frame.getSize());
        backgroundLabel = new JLabel(backgroundImage);
        backgroundLabel.setSize(frame.getSize());
        background.add(backgroundLabel);


        gamefield = new JPanel();
        gamefield.setLayout( new GridLayout(3,3,25,25));
        createButtons();

        frame.add(background);
        frame.add(gamefield);
    }
    
    void createButtons(){
        
        for(int index = 0; index<=9; index++){
            buttons.add(new JButton());
            if(index!=0){
                buttons.get(index).setOpaque(false);
                buttons.get(index).setContentAreaFilled(false);
                buttons.get(index).setBorderPainted(false);
                gamefield.add(buttons.get(index));
                buttons.get(index).addActionListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton){

            if(player==1){
                System.out.println( ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText() + "was clicked by player "+player);
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).setIcon(iconX);
                player++;
            }

            else{
                System.out.println( ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText() + "was clicked by player "+player);
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).setIcon(iconO);
                player--;
            }
            
        }
    }

    public TicTacToe(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        createGameField();

        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("TicTacToe");
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TicTacToe newGame = new TicTacToe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A FlowLayout will ensure your components will be rendered side by side.

Instead, on the panel that hosts all your UI elements, override [paintComponent()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) so it fills the background with your image. The component will still render it's children (the UI elements) on top of that.

Another chance would be to stack components on top of each other. The lower one would render your image, the upper one the UI - and do not forget to set opaque=false to the UI.